# I want to perform a statistical summary filtering by same value in multiple column

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, sapply

What I want is to calculate a summary on min_b12 and max_b12 filtering in the following columns: "tcn2_gc", "cubn_ag", "tcn1_ca", "tcn1_ct", "gif_tc", "fut2_ag", "fut2_ct", "fut2_gc", "fut2_ga1", "fut2_ga2" which can take the following values "wt", "het" or "hom", and iterating through them i.e. mean of  min_b12 for het value in "tcn2_gc", "cubn_ag", "tcn1_ca", "tcn1_ct", "gif_tc", "fut2_ag", "fut2_ct", "fut2_gc", "fut2_ga1", "fut2_ga2" (if the value is contained in this column)

Is it possible to get all wt values in the columns and calculate the summary for the quantitative variables: min_b12 and max_b12?

I didn't solve it in the way I wanted, with the iteration inserted in the code but I mean something like this and then run the summary

```
**EDIT1**

dat %>% 
dplyr::filter(rowAny(across(
          .cols = c(3:12),
        .fns = ~ str_detect(.,pattern = "hom")))) %>% get_summary_stats(show = c("mean", "median", "sd"))
```

```
dat <-  structure(list(nhc = c("1377869", "1846742", "1337543", "1163794", 
"93182", "824497", "323546", "1774490", "483286", "1899767", 
"304029", "636960", "959283", "284378", "204148", "147972", "1261182", 
"1417105", "1878731", "1013227", "1490875", "43983", "1770669", 
"288580", "606838", "1821185", "1575836", "1485052", "1049063", 
"628174", "525111", "270235", "1634302", "338306", "136137", 
"518591", "1757816", "424496", "1265440", "488214", "1020459", 
"1487395", "880355", "1786270", "1398711", "645253", "503181", 
"1738112", "620168", "140508", "1817020", "565507", "1800777", 
"377492", "871255", "535201", "1588527", "1229155", "190836", 
"1098429", "560259", "108680", "1821192", "517338", "298558", 
"984878", "241396", "540164", "1571582", "1278757", "1577674", 
"1290974", "1330190", "452300", "1759135", "1734156", "406266", 
"822936", "1804900", "1262901", "478486", "1338178", "208514", 
"815960", "992204", "1828805", "1772304", "350376", "1540876", 
"376343", "577322", "1002076", "1951320", "1630324", "1450928", 
"1913548", "1949565", "1248905", "1757332", "1041582", "678869", 
"1369832", "1158115", "1040319", "598169", "641996", "700553", 
"1657892", "1520276", "1295123", "1030324", "1827150", "1458965", 
"1674995", "363049", "520456", "203730", "139179", "1938496", 
"518516", "1406155", "1786937", "1799810", "1724881", "1802790", 
"1507312", "416898", "835159", "621885", "1687571", "945225", 
"902257", "1010906", "1868651", "484518", "1784494", "1774251", 
"1818319", "1076850", "1181523", "1879077", "1782498", "310737", 
"313743", "1792840", "1434583", "851547", "1536949", "1362380", 
"407970", "1767876", "204395", "1810918", "1448492", "346787", 
"651430", "1616999", "1283685", "1016859", "259625", "500712", 
"1340735", "1777470", "431835", "1630132", "423609", "840541", 
"138766", "1762533", "1811812", "381661", "226182", "1767597", 
"829888", "1235574", "1240675", "1822110", "1764115", "1125232", 
"19072", "42045", "1609746", "1486524", "1313093", "1052747", 
"1664397", "1779329", "504620", "1785803", "1793355", "185267", 
"1663664", "1192674", "118904", "1867262", "1603642", "1015556", 
"263401", "200483", "1205966", "1586420", "82934", "139119", 
"1215507", "146103", "985781", "962438", "1496183", "1611408", 
"911376", "853175", "989280", "652658", "36937", "393761", "1253410", 
"1233427", "460518", "1777914", "1809451", "657221", "1784475", 
"1520096", "1162607", "389932", "1636208", "835081", "1535526", 
"91820", "145122", "1754013", "1673855", "1762619", "1512455", 
"1412966", "689577", "1776809", "1380501", "40899", "1798054", 
"1002250"), tcn2_gc = c("hom", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
"wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "hom", "wt", "wt", "het", 
"wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "hom", 
"hom", "hom", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
"het", "hom", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", 
"wt", "het", "wt", "hom", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", 
"het", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "het", "het", "hom", "wt", "wt", 
"wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "hom", "het", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", 
"het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "het", 
"het", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", 
"wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", 
"wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
"wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "het", "het", "het", "wt", "het", "wt", 
"hom", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "hom", 
"wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "hom", 
"wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "het", "wt", 
"wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "het", "wt", "het", 
"hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
"hom", "wt", "het", "het", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
"hom", "wt", "wt", "het", "hom", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
"wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "het", "wt", "wt", "hom", 
"wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", 
"het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "het", "het", 
"het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "hom", "hom", "het", "wt", "wt", 
"wt", "het", "wt", "het", "wt"), cubn_ag = c("hom", "wt", "hom", 
"wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "hom", 
"wt", "hom", "het", "het", "het", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "het", 
"wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", 
"het", "het", "hom", "het", "hom", "het", "wt", "hom", "wt", 
"wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "hom", "hom", "wt", 
"wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "hom", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "hom", 
"het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "hom", "het", 
"wt", "wt", "hom", "het", "het", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
"wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "het", 
"wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "hom", "wt", 
"wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", 
"hom", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "hom", "hom", 
"hom", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
"het", "wt", "het", "hom", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
"wt", "hom", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", 
"het", "wt", "het", "wt", "hom", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", 
"wt", "hom", "wt", "het", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "het", 
"het", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "hom", "hom", "wt", "het", 
"wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "hom", "hom", "het", 
"wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "het", 
"hom", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "hom", "hom", "hom", "hom", 
"wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", 
"wt", "wt", "hom", "hom", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "hom", 
"hom", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "het", "wt"), tcn1_ca = c("wt", 
"wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
"wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
"wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
"wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
"het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
"wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
"wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "het", "wt", "wt", 
"wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
"wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", 
"wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
"wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", 
"wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
"wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
"wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
"wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
"wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", 
"wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
"wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
"het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
"wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
"wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
"wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
"wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt"), 
    tcn1_ct = c("wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "het", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt"), gif_tc = c("wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt"), fut2_ag = c("wt", "wt", 
    "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", 
    "wt", "wt", "het", "het", "het", "het", "wt", "het", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "hom", "hom", "wt", "hom", "het", "wt", "wt", 
    "het", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", 
    "hom", "het", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "hom", "hom", "wt", 
    "het", "wt", "wt", "het", "het", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "het", 
    "het", "wt", "hom", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", 
    "het", "hom", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "het", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "hom", 
    "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "het", 
    "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "het", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", 
    "wt", "het", "wt", "het", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "het", "het", "hom", "wt", "het", "het", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "hom", "hom", "het", "wt", "wt", "het", "hom", "wt", 
    "wt", "het", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", 
    "wt", "het", "het", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "hom", "hom", "wt", 
    "het", "wt", "wt", "hom", "hom", "hom", "hom", "wt", "hom", 
    "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", 
    "het", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "het", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt"), fut2_ct = c("wt", 
    "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "hom", "wt", "wt", "het", "het", "het", "het", "wt", "het", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "hom", "wt", "hom", "het", "wt", 
    "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", 
    "wt", "hom", "het", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "hom", "hom", 
    "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "het", "het", "het", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "het", 
    "het", "wt", "hom", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", 
    "het", "hom", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "het", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "hom", 
    "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "het", 
    "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "het", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", 
    "wt", "het", "wt", "het", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "het", "het", "hom", "wt", "het", "het", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "hom", "hom", "het", "wt", "wt", "het", "hom", "wt", 
    "wt", "het", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", 
    "wt", "het", "het", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "hom", "hom", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "hom", "hom", "wt", "hom", 
    "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", 
    "het", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "het", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt"), fut2_gc = c("wt", 
    "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "hom", "wt", "wt", "het", "het", "het", "het", "wt", "het", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "hom", "wt", "hom", "het", "wt", 
    "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", 
    "wt", "hom", "het", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "hom", "hom", 
    "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "het", "het", "het", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "het", 
    "het", "wt", "hom", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", 
    "het", "hom", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "het", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "hom", 
    "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "het", 
    "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "het", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", 
    "het", "wt", "het", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "het", "het", "hom", "wt", "het", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "hom", "hom", "het", "wt", "wt", "het", "hom", "wt", "wt", 
    "het", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", 
    "het", "het", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "hom", "hom", "wt", "het", 
    "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "hom", "hom", "wt", "hom", "wt", 
    "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "het", 
    "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "het", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt"), fut2_ga1 = c("wt", 
    "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "hom", "wt", "wt", "het", "het", "het", "het", "wt", "het", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "hom", "wt", "hom", "het", "wt", 
    "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", 
    "wt", "hom", "het", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "hom", "hom", 
    "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "het", "het", "het", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "het", 
    "het", "wt", "hom", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", 
    "het", "hom", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "het", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "hom", 
    "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "het", 
    "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "het", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", 
    "wt", "het", "wt", "het", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "het", "het", "hom", "wt", "het", "het", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "hom", "hom", "het", "wt", "wt", "het", "hom", "wt", 
    "wt", "het", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", 
    "wt", "het", "het", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "hom", "hom", "wt", 
    "het", "wt", "wt", "hom", "hom", "hom", "hom", "wt", "hom", 
    "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", 
    "het", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "het", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt"), fut2_ga2 = c("wt", 
    "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "hom", "wt", "wt", "het", "het", "het", "het", "wt", "het", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "hom", "wt", "hom", "het", "wt", 
    "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", 
    "wt", "hom", "het", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "hom", "hom", 
    "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "het", "het", "het", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "het", 
    "het", "wt", "hom", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", 
    "het", "hom", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "het", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "hom", 
    "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "het", 
    "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "het", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", 
    "wt", "het", "wt", "het", "wt", "het", "het", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "het", "het", "hom", "wt", "het", "hom", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "hom", "hom", "het", "wt", "wt", "het", "hom", "wt", 
    "wt", "het", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", 
    "wt", "het", "het", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "hom", "hom", "wt", 
    "het", "wt", "wt", "hom", "hom", "hom", "hom", "wt", "hom", 
    "wt", "wt", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", 
    "het", "hom", "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "het", 
    "wt", "wt", "wt", "wt", "het", "wt", "wt", "wt"), max_b12 = c(82, 
    114, 493, 275, 141, 145, 146, 1343, 378, 165, 180, 183, 298, 
    220, 244, 296, 307, 237, 204, 205, 3309, 246, 206, 580, 208, 
    212, 213, 270, 394, 299, 290, 228, 217, 218, 384, 494, 220, 
    306, 221, 364, 328, 224, 224, 225, 328, 226, 227, 310, 228, 
    229, 286, 229, 231, 231, 631, 870, 312, 237, 281, 247, 238, 
    240, 240, 240, 262, 241, 242, 345, 243, 244, 296, 270, 244, 
    244, 245, 246, 6151, 247, 250, 314, 339, 250, 252, 324, 455, 
    256, 272, 341, 258, 318, 258, 336, 260, 397, 324, 263, 264, 
    265, 336, 407, 298, 388, 270, 656, 271, 287, 372, 273, 385, 
    279, 280, 281, 354, 288, 513, 493, 292, 293, 293, 294, 294, 
    296, 296, 324, 298, 300, 349, 302, 410, 304, 354, 305, 331, 
    307, 356, 308, 308, 308, 311, 311, 311, 315, 318, 320, 320, 
    388, 835, 322, 323, 408, 325, 325, 326, 371, 420, 329, 334, 
    334, 559, 340, 340, 474, 342, 344, 344, 346, 360, 346, 348, 
    350, 351, 451, 353, 354, 580, 359, 361, 378, 595, 370, 404, 
    371, 514, 374, 388, 378, 703, 419, 388, 390, 571, 399, 569, 
    404, 407, 411, 812, 421, 423, 426, 428, 429, 730, 437, 433, 
    435, 1062, 451, 474, 744, 468, 477, 511, 497, 502, 523, 555, 
    556, 559, 570, 631, 712, 609, 614, 616, 970, 641, 917, 652, 
    661, 685, 689, 797, 2719, 826, 843, 894, 2244, 1703, 2336, 
    2568), min_b12 = c(61, 114, 121, 130, 141, 145, 146, 149, 
    151, 165, 180, 183, 196, 198, 201, 202, 202, 204, 204, 205, 
    205, 205, 206, 207, 208, 212, 213, 214, 214, 214, 215, 217, 
    217, 218, 218, 219, 220, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 224, 225, 
    226, 226, 227, 228, 228, 229, 229, 229, 231, 231, 233, 236, 
    237, 237, 238, 238, 238, 240, 240, 240, 240, 241, 242, 243, 
    243, 244, 244, 244, 244, 244, 245, 246, 246, 247, 250, 250, 
    250, 250, 252, 253, 253, 256, 256, 257, 258, 258, 258, 260, 
    260, 262, 263, 263, 264, 265, 266, 266, 269, 270, 270, 271, 
    271, 272, 273, 273, 275, 279, 280, 281, 283, 288, 289, 292, 
    292, 293, 293, 294, 294, 296, 296, 297, 298, 300, 301, 302, 
    303, 304, 305, 305, 306, 307, 308, 308, 308, 308, 311, 311, 
    311, 315, 318, 320, 320, 321, 321, 322, 323, 325, 325, 325, 
    326, 326, 329, 329, 334, 334, 334, 340, 340, 341, 342, 344, 
    344, 346, 346, 346, 348, 350, 351, 353, 353, 354, 356, 359, 
    361, 361, 364, 370, 370, 371, 373, 374, 376, 378, 381, 386, 
    388, 390, 394, 399, 401, 404, 407, 411, 414, 421, 423, 426, 
    428, 429, 431, 431, 433, 435, 450, 451, 461, 461, 468, 477, 
    480, 497, 502, 523, 532, 556, 559, 570, 589, 592, 609, 614, 
    616, 620, 641, 644, 652, 661, 685, 689, 797, 819, 826, 843, 
    894, 955, 976, 2147, 2568)), row.names = c(NA, -241L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most elegant but it should work - assuming I understood everything correctly (for future question I recommend posting an example of the desired output). Proceed similarly for the other variables (one could consider, e.g., nesting loops):

```
list.het.mean_min_b12 <- list()

for (str.colname in c("tcn2_gc", "cubn_ag", "tcn1_ca", "tcn1_ct", "gif_tc", "fut2_ag", "fut2_ct", "fut2_gc", "fut2_ga1", "fut2_ga2")) {
  list.het.mean_min_b12[[str.colname]] <- (test %>% 
    select(all_of(str.colname), min_b12) %>% 
    group_by(.data[[str.colname]]) %>% 
    summarize(mean_min_b12 = mean(min_b12)) %>% 
    pull(mean_min_b12, all_of(str.colname)))["het"] # %>% unname() # uncomment if you do not want the name "het" for the vector returned from `pull` - of course only after selecting it with `["het"]`
}

# output
> list.het.mean_min_b12
$tcn2_gc
     het 
400.0213 

$cubn_ag
     het 
  368.75 

$tcn1_ca
     het 
289.4286
```

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't able to run it

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are looking for. But you might find `pivot_longer()` from `tidyr` to be useful.

```r
dat |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = tcn2_gc:fut2_ga2) %>% 
  group_by(name, value) %>% 
  summarize(max_b12 = mean(max_b12), 
            min_b12 = mean(min_b12), 
            .groups = "drop")
```

This produces output like this:

```
# A tibble: 30 × 4
   name     value max_b12 min_b12
   <chr>    <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 cubn_ag  het      608.    369.
 2 cubn_ag  hom      459.    340.
 3 cubn_ag  wt       414.    343.
 4 fut2_ag  het      497.    322.
 5 fut2_ag  hom      415.    345.
 6 fut2_ag  wt       448.    354.
 7 fut2_ct  het      498.    320.
 8 fut2_ct  hom      403.    341.
 9 fut2_ct  wt       449.    356.
10 fut2_ga1 het      497.    322.
```

If you want the mean of `het` across all values in `name`, remove `name` from `group_by()`, etc.

Comment: No, I wasn't saying that. Thanks for the contribution. I was saying filtering using sthg like rowAny or if_any

Comment: If you want all cases where the `value == "wt"` (in terms of my output above), then that should be easy. After `pivot_longer()`, just `filter(value == "wt")` and then `summarise()`. You would not `group_by()` if you want means across all values of `name` (in terms of my output above).